# Replace sub-expressions matching a pattern unless located under specific heads

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, symbolic, expression-manipulation, rule

Suppose I have some rule, e.g. `Re[x_] :> (x + Conjugate[x])/2`. I want to apply it to all matching sub-expressions in some expression, excluding any sub-expressions that are located somewhere under heads `Hold[…]` or `Function[…]` (at any depth). What is the simplest way to do that? Can it be done without explicit filtering of positions?

---

For example, the result of replacement in the expression:

```
{z + Re[a], Hold[1 + Re[b]], Function[z, Abs[Re[c]]]}
```

should be

```
{z + (a + Conjugate[a])/2, Hold[1 + Re[b]], Function[z, Abs[Re[c]]]}
```

where `Re[b]` and `Re[c]` are left unmodified, because they are located under `Hold` and `Function`.

Comment: Vladimir, an example of  _some expression_ would make it so much easier to answer your question.

Comment: It seems that my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6451802/305118

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the patterns you want to avoid in your replacement rule:

```
ReplaceAll[
    {z + Re[a], Hold[1 + Re[b]], Function[z, Abs[Re[c]]]},
    {
        h:(_Hold | _Function) :> h,
        Re[x_] :> (x+Conjugate[x])/2
    }
]
```

> {z + 1/2 (a + Conjugate[a]), Hold[1 + Re[b]], Function[z, Abs[Re[c]]]}